# Use Onfocus and Onclick to select text in a textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to select all the text in a textbox when tabbed over to the text box and when its clicked. Thought I had a good thing when I had `function selectField() {$(this).select();}` to select it but then I discovered that I could just use onfocus and onclick and set those directly with `this.select();` Problem is that I can do it when I tab to the text field but clicking it. Have a fiddle showing what I'm talking about http://jsfiddle.net/t9jJX/

edit. When I click the textbox the highlighted text does not stay highlighted.

Comment: Everything works fine here... I am not sure what your problem is?

Comment: When I click the textbox the text does not stay selected.

Comment: Works fine in IE, what browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome. Did not think to test in IE yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("input").on('mouseup',function(){
    $(this).focus().select(); 
});
```

I also removed the `onclick` and `onfocus` attributes throughout the HTML. Tested successfully in Chrome and IE.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/t9jJX/2/

Answer (score 1):

The problem with attaching `this.select()` to `onfocus`. Use click only and your code will work fine:

```
<input id="before" type="text" />

<input id="unit"  onclick="this.select();" type="text" />

<input id="Cost"  onclick="this.select();" type="text"  value="123" />

<input id="after" type="text"/>
```

EDIT:
The reason for this seems to be that chrome places the carat in the text on mouseup, but fires `onfocus` on mousedown. Using the `onfocus` event to select isn't working quite right because chrome selects everything, and then deselects it when in places the carat in the text.

The same behavior is evident if you test `onmousedown="this.select()"` and `onmouseup="this.select"`